# Cannot use '&' operator in Gnu AS expression

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

I would like to get the address of a variable and'ed by 4096 (which would correspond to the address of its memory page). Since this is something that can be computed offline I did something that looks like this (v is the variable and vpage should contain the address of its page):

```
    .data
    v:        .zero 0x100
    vpage:  .long v & 0xfffff000
```

Trying to compile this file with the x86 assembler results in the following error:

```
test.S: Assembler messages:
test.S:3: Error: invalid sections for operation on `v' and `L0'
```

Why would GAS refuse to compute this? Now the weird part: replace '&' by "+" and the code will compile and the address will even be correctly computed after link. Any hint on the why of this behavior or how to fix it would be very welcome.

Comment: gas is typically used as an backend assembler. The compiler will already have evaluated all constant expressions

Comment: @Marco In that case I guess the best I could do would be to switch to NASM or YASM...

Comment: For nontrivial amounts: yes. Or use compiler inline assembler, and let your compiler fix it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with this is that GAS generates object files that will be processed by the linker(s). While GAS does support bitwise AND operation, it can not do so with absolute addresses. They are subject to change by the linker, and hence GAS must generate relocation entries that only support limited operations (mainly just offsetting). If you can turn your absolute address into (local) relative address GAS can compute it during assembly time. Otherwise, you will have to do it from code at runtime.

Comment: Great answer. The problem is easy to workaround by invoking gcc instead of as and using the C preprocessor for that, but you allowed me to understand the why of this behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Intel syntax you can use `_AND`, `_OR`, `_NOT`, `_SHL`, `_SHR` and maybe others to accomplish this.  This might work in GNU's assembler as well.

Comment: Unfortunately GAS does not recognize those.